# Macro Functions in C - Logic as argument?

Tags: c, macros, directive

I have encountered the following macro definition and I am trying to understand its use and its syntax and logic:

```
#define FOREACH(elem, list, body) {\
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size(list); ++i)\
    {\
        int elem;\
        if (get_elem(list, i, &value)) {\
            body\
        }\
    }\
}
```

I have come across macro functions before, however they were simpler and never included this much logic in them. What I did not understand mainly, what the `body` parameter is. **Is it possible to pass in certain logic to be added to the function in place of the parameter name?**

*I didn't write this directive so I am not sure whether there are any errors in it.*

Comment: There is nothing so difficult about a `for` loop that makes it a good treatment by macro. And this will only work if `list` is an actual array, not a function argument defined as an array but it depends on what `size()` and `get_elem()` do, also what `value` is has not been supplied to the function.

Comment: @WeatherVane: that I did not get also, the `value` as in, since it hasn't been defined anywhere. I am assuming `int elem` should have been declared as `int value`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Nothing in that macro body requires an array at all, let alone “an actual array.“ `list` could be a structure that is a header for a linked list, with the size contained in the structure, for example.

Comment: @EricPostpischil which is why I wrote "but it depends on what `size()` does". I did not use the word 'requires'.

Comment: A macro is nothing more than a text substitution at the preprocessing stage.  "Logic" is just text during preprocessing, so it can be a macro parameter as in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass arbitrary logic as `body` parameter. It will be pasted here:

```
     if (get_elem(list, i, &value)) {\
        body\
    }\
```

Comment: Can it be multiple lines of logic?

Comment: Yes, macro just pastes code there, either single symbol or a page of code. One more thing to mention is that in my opinion it is better to have `body;\` instead of just `body\` because it would make code a bit more readable in case of simple one liners like `FOREACH(e, l, update())`